# Loading multiple pickle files..the process keep getting killed

Tags: python, process, out-of-memory, pickle

I'm working with a big dataset, and trying to load the data from some pickle files to start training a deep learning model. The files are seven with each having ~2.3GB of what's supposed to be nodes in a graph with each its pandas dataframe, basically the files all together should contain around 170k nodes.

Now, when I try to load the files into an object that must contain all of the nodes (this is how the model was implemented) the process keeps getting killed to what I think is being out of memory most probably.
Would there be any workaround this out of memory issue ? (maybe worth noting but I'm working on a machine with 64GB of RAM)

Comment: The amount of RAM is irrelevant, except as it affects performance. User processes use virtual memory, RAM is hidden.

Comment: So what would be the problem then in this case ?

Comment: You're running out of virtual memory.

Comment: yes, is there any way around that ? I don't have the option to change how it must be as an input to the model so I want to find a way to do/force that ?

Comment: Can you release memory as you go? Use `delete` to delete the object and call `gc.collect()` perhaps?